# MDP JMS Transaction rolls back then reprocesses message in an endless loop

Tags: java, spring, jms

If I enable transaction management on my DefaultMessageListenerContainer by specifying `sessionTransacted=true` or `transactionManager=jmsTransactionManager`, whenever an exception occurs in the MDP, the transaction is rolled back and the message is placed back on the queue. That then causes the message to be processed again, the transaction to roll back again over and over again so that it creates an endless loop.

I guess my question is ... what am I missing here? Why would you want the message to go back on the queue if it just means it will be processed over and over again?

```
<!-- jms connection factory -->
<bean name="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- jms transaction manager -->
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Destination for Inbound_Email_Q -->
<bean name="inboundEmailDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="queue/inbound_Email_Queue" />
</bean>

<!-- JmsTemplate for Inbound_Email_Q -->
<bean name="jmsInboundEmailTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="inboundEmailDestination" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="xmlMessageConverter" />
</bean>

<!-- jms asynchronous listener -->
<bean id="emailMessageServiceMdp" class="org.site.wso.core.jms.EmailMessageServiceMdp" />
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <!-- <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager" />  -->
    <!-- <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>  -->
    <property name="destination" ref="inboundEmailDestination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
</bean>

<!-- jms message listener adapter -->
<bean id="messageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.site.wso.core.jms.EmailMessageServiceMdp"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="xmlMessageConverter"/>
</bean>
```

And here is my MDP:

```
public class EmailMessageServiceMdp implements MessageDelegate {

    public void handleMessage(Object object) {

        EmailMessageRequestVO requestVO = (EmailMessageRequestVO) object;   

        try {
            //Service call that throw exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ApplicationException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message redelivery is simply the default behaviour for your [configured] JMS implementation. It's up for endless debate what the relative usefulness of this is, but it would seem that rather than discard a message with some potentially unrecoverable data, some sort of retry is a sensible and conservative approach. For example, in your case, you appear to be converting a JMS message to an email message and dispatching to an SMTP server. If the SMTP gateway is down, you might want to hold onto the JMS messages and reprocess them when the gateway comes back up.

In general I would say your options for handling a message that failed processing are (depending on the JMS implementation):

1. Ditch the message.
2. Write the message to an error queue.
3. Redeliver the message after a delay of *n* seconds.
4. Redeliver the message *n* times and then write the message to an error queue.
5. Redeliver the message after a delay of *n* seconds *x* times and then write the message to an error queue.

If you prefer #1, then simply suppress the exception, commit the transaction and wave good bye to the message. For the rest, the JMS configuration (or the destination specific configuration) should handle those.

Additionally, if you want something more specific, you can interrogate the message's [getJMSRedelivered()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSRedelivered%28%29) and/or the implementation specific message header property that indicates how many times the message has been redelivered  (supported by most JMS implementations, but not standard) and dispose of the message accordingly.

Comment: Nicholas, this answer is so well put that I wish i could give it 5 upvotes! I'll probably be looking into 2) or 5) from above ... that seems to be a reasonable way to hold onto a message that can't be processed immediately if a resource is down, like in the scenario you mention.

Comment: Hey, thanks. What JMS implementation *are* you using ? You may be able to configure this problem away.

Comment: JBossMQ. I hope that's the case, but I fear configuration may not be an option. I looked into this briefly and came across something that stated that this may be possible using the "dead letter queue", but only if the messages are being read in an MDB (which I'm not as I'm consuming them in a Spring Message Driven Pojo). I'm not certain about that though, so let me know if you know of anything to the contrary!

Comment: Information on the DLQ configuration for an MDB can be found here: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/The_EJB_Client_Side_View-Specifying_the_EJB_Proxy_Configuration.html (See DLQConfig) As far as I can tell (and from what I read), this can only be configured for an MDB.

Comment: Very useful Q&A. In my particuar situation I would like the MDP listener to stop, any way to achieve that in a soft way, without resorting to System.exit() and such?

Comment: Yes. In JBoss, you can start/stop the MDB delivery through JMX.