# Spring Jms Listener goes to Infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, solace

I have the below config for solace queue listener .Since one message throws error .It goes into infine loop ,.How to solve this ?

```
@Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsContainer() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory container = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        container.setConnectionFactory(solaceCachedConnectionFactory());
       container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
       container.setSessionTransacted(true);
       container.setErrorHandler(exampleErrorHandler);//error handler logs the message
        return container;
    }

@JmsListener(destination = "myqueue", containerFactory = "jmsContainer", concurrency = "5-10")
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        
        try {
            
            LOG.info("In here START onMessage " +  msg.toString()) ;
            
            if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                
                System.out.println(" In here ");
                
                MyClass c=gson.fromJson(((TextMessage) msg).getText(),MyClass.class); // throw error here
```

Answer (score 2):

in short it's because of your `sessionTransacted=true`.
This means that in case of exception thrown, the message is put back on the queue and it will be consumed and retried again.

See: [MDP JMS Transaction rolls back then reprocesses message in an endless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538678/mdp-jms-transaction-rolls-back-then-reprocesses-message-in-an-endless-loop) for suggestions on handling retry and failures